# A point $a=(a_1,...,a_n)$ is isolated point in the cartesian product

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let be $M$ a metric space. A point $a=(a_1,...,a_n)$ is isolated point in the cartesian product $M=M_1\times...\times M_n$, if and only if, each coordinates $a_i$ is a isolated point in $M_i$

My approach: Let $p_i:M\to M_i$, with $i={1,...,n}$, the projection defines by $p_i(a)=a_i$, then $p_i$ is a continuous function. And if, each coordinates of $a$ is a isolated point, then each point is like a open ball and therefore $a$ is formed only by isolated points. But I don't have really sure of this, maybe exist another way to prove this.

Answer (score -1):

a_i isolated means there is U open nbd of a_i containing only a_i for i=1,...,n. Take the product U of these nbds and this a nbd of A=(a_1,...,a_n that contains only A.